# Looking for a nice characterisation of functors $F$ whose precomposition functor $F^*$ is full

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\newcommand{\Obj}{\mathrm{Obj}}$[Adámek–Bashir–Sobral–Velebil's *On Functors Which Are Lax Epimorphisms*](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n20/8-20abs.html) proves the following result:

> Let $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ be a functor. The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. For each category $\mathcal{X}$, the precomposition by $F$ functor
>    $$F^{*}\colon\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{X})\to\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{X})$$
>    is full.
> 2. The components
>    $$\epsilon_G\colon\mathrm{Lan}_F(G\circ F)\to G$$
>    of the counit
>    $$\epsilon\colon\mathrm{Lan}_F(-\circ F)\Rightarrow\mathrm{id}_{\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{D},\mathcal{X})}$$
>    of the adjunction $\mathrm{Lan}\dashv F^*$ are all split monomorphisms.
> 3. For each $B\in\Obj(\mathcal{D})$, there exist:
>
>    - An object $A_{B}$ of $\mathcal{C}$
>    - A morphism $r_{B}\colon F(A_{B})\to B$ of $\mathcal{D}$
>    - A morphism $s_{B}\colon B\to F(A_{B})$ of $\mathcal{D}$;
>
>    satisfying the following condition:
>
>    - $(\star)$ For each $A\in\Obj(\mathcal{C})$ and each pair of morphisms
>      \begin{align*}
>                r &\colon F(A) \to B,\\
>                s &\colon B    \to F(A)
>             \end{align*}
>      of $\mathcal{D}$, we have an equality of equivalence classes
>      $$[(A_{B},s_{B},r_{B})]=[(A,s,r\circ s_{B}\circ r_{B})]$$
>      in $\int^{A\in\mathcal{C}}h^{B'}_{F_{A}}\times h^{F_{A}}_{B}$.

As one can see, these conditions are really messy. Are there any other characterisations of functors such that $F^*$ is full but "cleaner" than the above ones?